# Best way to handle page numbers in MySQL bibliography?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I’m trying to work out the structure for a bibliography database with three basic entities: `text` (essays, articles, etc.), `publication` (the books, journals, etc. that contain those texts), and `maker` (authors, editors, etc.).

Page numbers are turning out to be one of the trickier parts of this. Because the rules for formatting number ranges in English are complicated, I wanted to let the software do the formatting and have users just input individual page numbers. Initially I had these as columns in the `text` table:

```
first_page SMALLINT,
last_page SMALLINT
```

But that won’t work for a magazine article like this one that jumps from page 135 to page 206:

- Ringen, Jonathan. “Wireless Evolution.” *Metropolis*, June 2003, 130–35, 206–7.

Also, newspaper page numbers are often alphanumerics, like “C9–C10”, “1E, 7E” or “WC13.”

So it seems like I need an extra table, `page_range`, and a datatype change:

```
range_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
text_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES text(text_id),
first_page VARCHAR,
last_page VARCHAR,
range_ordinal TINYINT
```

My question: Is this really the best way to do this? It feels excessive to create a whole table for what is essentially just an attribute of `text`. Am I on the right track, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a string with a series of page ranges, then you can use `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`. But treat this string as verbatim. That is, you can store the full list, or fetch the full list, as an atomic string. You don't use SQL expressions to search or sort or edit the list.

But if you want to use SQL expressions to work with individual page ranges, for example to count how many ranges, or edit the list of page ranges, or search for a specific page range, then create the second table and store them on multiple rows of that table.

Some people use JSON to store an "array" of values on a single row, but in many ways this makes your queries *harder*, not easier.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down into the three options and providing use cases; that makes the decision very clear.